# Plotting Related Data on Map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Not sure anyone can help with this:

I have 2 dataframes: One is a list of lat/long coordinates that form the map of New York's 77 police precincts. The other is a list of crime data for NYC, showing the amount of murders, car thefts, and assaults for each precinct, by year.

I've plotted the precincts on a map with ggplot. How do I overlay that map with, for example, the amount of murders in each precinct using colors? IE, red for precincts with the most murders down to green for the least.

The map dataframe is set up like this:

```
Lat  |   Long  | Precinct 
-74  |    40.2 |      <2>
```

and the crime dataframe is set up like this:

```
  Crime | Year | Value | Precinct
Assault |   03 | 2300  |      <2>
```

Here is how I plotted the map:

```
y <- ggplot(data = MyShapeMapData, aes(x = long, y = lat))
y + geom_polygon(aes(group = group), fill = NA, colour = "black") + coord_fixed(1.3)
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like the following (shown with some dummy data)?

```
MyShapeMapData <- read.csv(text='lat,   long, Precinct 
-74.01,40.71,<2>
-74.00,40.72,<3>', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
MyCrimeData <- read.csv(text='Crime, Year, Value, Precinct
Assault, 03, 2300,<2>
Murder,04, 700,<3>', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(ggmap)
mymap <- get_map(location = "New York", zoom=15)

library(dplyr)
df <- inner_join(MyShapeMapData, MyCrimeData, by='Precinct')
df
#     lat  long Precinct   Crime Year Value
#1 -74.01 40.71      <2> Assault    3  2300
#2 -74.00 40.72      <3>  Murder    4   700
ggmap(mymap) + geom_point(data = df, aes(x = lat, y = long, color=Crime, size=Value)) + scale_size(range = c(10,20)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue', 'red')) #, alpha=0.5) + coord_fixed(1.3)
```

[image]

Comment: Will joining the data frames work though? There are several hundred lat/long points that make up each precinct, not 1

Comment: Which is fine, but do we have any other option other than joining, since you have 2 different data frames, probably we can try joining with data.table that will be faster.

Comment: I guess I'm confused, because the precinct map dataframe has like hundreds of rows for each precinct, so where would the 105 rows of crime for each precinct match up? I'm going to try it now

Comment: when i inner_join by Precinct, i end up with 11.5 million rows to the resulting dataset. Each and every lat/long point representing a point on the border of a precinct is joined by the entire set of crime data for that precinct. Is that normal?

Comment: Yes it could be, since the number of rows for a Cartesian product of tables with m rows and n columns is m*n rows and the Cartesian product is the worst case for (left-right outer) join, in case of inner join it will be much less.

Comment: If it's not required to show all the crimes at once, then we can first subset the datasets w.r.t. crimes and then for each crime do inner join to combine the tables and then visualize for each crime, the number of rows will be reduced many times.

Comment: It is at least graphing the crime data as a whole! The end goal is to have users choose a crime and then slide from year 2000-2015 as the map updates the crime values for each precinct, but that is a long way off